The system hangs when reading a large number of files on NTFS
System - Kubuntu 22.04
I have several ssd drives installed: 1 for windows (ntfs), 1 for kubuntu, 1 - file dump (ntfs), well, 1 more for games (ntfs).
I use two systems, so it is important to be able to use the ntfs file system. Fortunately, kubuntu with its kde took care of this and automatically mounts all disks.
I used this build for several years, but recently I encountered a very painful problem. When I open a project (code base) located on an ntfs disk using IDE (PHPStorm), there is a very high chance that the entire system will immediately hang without showing any signs of life. Moreover, after rebooting, the disk will not be mounted and in order to see it, you will have to boot Windows and run the chkdsk command.
I have no idea how to solve this and why this even arose.
Perhaps this is somehow related, but in the KDE settings the Removable Devices section stopped opening for me (eternal loading).

Same issue on my machine, although it started happening only recently after having migrated from 22.04 LTS to 24.04 LTS

"you will have to boot Windows and run the chkdsk command."  then that is a bug and needs to be reported https://github.com/tuxera/ntfs-3g   Likely someone needs to check from the windows end what the problem is and then backtrack it into the driver.  Our driver is generic so not maintained by Ubuntu and it can be caused by a change on the windows end. You will not find an answer here unless there is a bug fix.
